# Пересечение двух циклических списков

Tags: c++, список

Результат содержит элементы, одновременно присутствующие в обеих структурах данных. Как это реализовать на с++?

Comment: А какие требования к решению? Например, скопировать все элементы в два `set` и применить `set_intersection` - годится?

Comment: Никаких, наверное годится.